# filter a pyspark dataframe with maximum timestamp value

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with many columns and there is one timestamp column namely "modified_time". I need to filter the rows of the dataframe with the latest modified_time or by getting the max of the modified_time value.

dataframe:

```
Col1  Col2  Modified_time
1     ABC   2022-03-01 08:55:29.423
2     DEF   2022-03-01 08:55:29.423
3     GHI   2022-03-01 08:55:29.423
1     ABC   2022-02-28 12:43:17.142
2     DEF   2022-02-27 23:31:26.777
3     GHI   2022-02-18 06:17:11.534
```

expected output

```
Col1  Col2  Modified_time
  1     ABC   2022-03-01 08:55:29.423
  2     DEF   2022-03-01 08:55:29.423
  3     GHI   2022-03-01 08:55:29.423
```

something similar to this:

```
filtered_df where modified_time = max(modified_time)
```

I did try the following code:

```
df = spark.read.format("delta").table("tableName")
max_ts = df.agg({"_modified_time": "max"}).collect()[0][0]
df.filter(df._modified_time==max_ts).show(truncate = False)
```

However, when I use the above code in my overall flow, the dataframe does not filter. It returns all the records.

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
RLH

Comment: not able to reproduce on my side with the same code provided.. could you add some data to reproduce your case?

Comment: I have edited the question with the details. Basically I need the rows which have the maximum timestamp values.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in your max query you are using **`_modified_time`** instead of `modified_time`.

Then in your filter change the same from **`_modified_time`** to `modified_time`

***Example:***

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([('1','ABC','2022-03-01 08:55:29.423'),('2','DEF','2022-03-01 08:55:29.423'),
                         ('3','GHI','2022-03-01 08:55:29.423'),('1','ABC','2022-02-28 12:43:17.142'),('2','DEF','2022-02-27 23:31:26.777'),
                         ('3','GHI','2022-02-18 06:17:11.534 '),
                         ],['col1','col2','modified_time'])
max_ts = df.agg({"modified_time": "max"}).collect()[0][0]
df.filter(df.modified_time==max_ts).show(truncate = False)
```